# SonarQube build breaker and Jenkins quality gates not same

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have `SonarQube` (v6.7) installed using `sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.2` for quality gates. I have `Jenkins` (v2.161) installed with `Sonar Quality Gates Plugin` (v1.3.1) installed in different Servers. Below is the configuration of the Quality gates in Jenkins

[image]

I have configured the Project key and Job status as FAILED in the job configuration. The problem is, when the SonarQube analysis for a project is triggered from maven using cmd prompt, it is passed successfully. When the same job is triggered from Jenkins I am getting below error.

```
07:03:50 [INFO] Quality gate status: ERROR
07:03:50 [ERROR] Security Rating on New Code: 4 > 1
07:03:50 [ERROR] Reliability Rating on New Code: 4 > 1
07:03:50 [ERROR] [BUILD BREAKER] Project did not meet 2 conditions
07:03:51 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
07:03:51 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
07:03:51 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
07:03:51 [INFO] Total time: 02:17 min
07:03:51 [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-06T07:03:51+01:00
07:03:51 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
07:03:51 Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
07:03:52 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project Project-company-lib: Project does not pass the quality gate. -> [Help 1]
07:03:52 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project Project-company-lib: Project does not pass the quality gate.
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference in report for SonarQube trigger and Jenkins Job is that, I have a configuration in SonarQube to analyse only `.java,.jav` files .In the SonarQube UI, Configurations --> General Settings --> Java, this configuration is available.

The project consists of `.java,.xml,.xhtml` files, so in order to skip the files other than java, I have included a configuration `-Dsonar.language=java` in the Jenkins goal and now the report is same. Though this configuration is said to be deprecated, it works fine for now.